# Clarify if the topological sum on $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$ is equal to the usual topology.

Tags: general-topology

> For a collection $\mathscr{X}=\{(X_j ,\mathcal{T}_j):j\in J\}$ of topological spaces let be $X:=\bigcup_{j\in J}X_j$ and for each $j\in J$ let be $\iota_j:X_j\rightarrow X$ the inclusion map defined through the condition
> $$
> \iota_j(x)=x
> $$
> for any $x\in X$ and thus let be $\mathcal{F}=\{\iota_j:j\in J\}$ the collection of such functions. So we say that $X$ is the topological sum of the collection $\mathscr X$ if it is equipped with the final topology induced by the collection $\mathscr F$ as above defined.

So now I ask to clarify if it is true that the usual product toplogy on $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$ is equal to the topological sum induced by the collection $\mathscr{X}:=\Big\{\{x\}\times\Bbb R^n:x\in\Bbb R^n\Big\}$ where $\{x\}\times\Bbb R^n$ is obviously equipped with the subspace topology induced by the product topology of $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$. So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously not, as the topological sum is disconnected and the product topology on $\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^n$ is not (it's just $\Bbb R^{2n}$ so connected as can be).

Comment: Oh yeah! This because $\bigcup_{x\in\Bbb R^n\setminus\{\xi\}}\Big(\{x\}\times\Bbb R^n\Big)$ and $\{\xi\}\times\Bbb R^n$ for any $\xi\in\Bbb R^n$ are two disjoint open sets with respect sum topology whose union is just $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Indeed they are.

Comment: Okay, all clear. Thanks too much for your assistance!